# Create a 2D array in java to store two kinds of objects

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I have a superclass `Agent`. The superclass `Agent` has two subclasses: 1. `User` ; 2. `Seller`. And these two sub classes are the superclass of `User_action` and `Seller_action`. I want to create two objects. The first object is of class `User_action`. The aim behind creating this object is that it should inherit the variables and methods of class `Agent` and class `User` (and, I hope I am achieving this aim.). And, I create the second object from class `Seller_action` with the similar objective in mind (inherit variables and methods from class `Agent` and class `Seller`.).

Once, I create these objects  (or instances I believe) I want to store them in a 2D array. I don't know how to do this. And, this is my first attempt with java, so I have read very basic stuff and now I am trying to improve as I code.

Now, my problem is:How can I store two kinds of obejcts..in something. You see, the reason I want to do this is because I want all the objects to be present on a geographical coordinate and I want to know every one's coordinate or geographical position (x,y). And, as I come from MATLAB the best way to do this is to store it in an Matrix (2D array in JAVA).

I will appreciate any advice. Many thanks!

Comment: At least you should have written a wrong code.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: One array can store only one kind of data , so only one kind of object coming from one class. I need a 2D array that can store two kinds of objects, i.e. Objects coming from two different classes. How can I do this?

Comment: Or Can I even do it using an array...or should I use somthing else that JAVA has to offer???

Comment: I am not able to understand how you wish to store / access the object and its data. Can you give a more clear idea about it? Are you looking to store object1.value, object2.value1 as a pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you are looking to design the classes in the following manner such that objects ua and sa(defined below) inherit all the values from their parent:

Agent is the Parent class:

```
class Agent {  //the parent class

}
```

Class User is sub class of Agent

```
class User extends Agent{   //user is subclass of Agent
    int Agent_1,Agent_2;
    User()
    {
        Agent_1 = 1;
        Agent_2 = 2;
    }
}
```

Class Seller is sub class of Agent

```
class Seller extends Agent{   //Seller is sub class of Agent

    int Seller_1, Seller_2;
    Seller()
    {
        Seller_1 = 3;
        Seller_2 = 4;
    }
}
```

User_action is subclass of User

```
class User_action  extends User{   //user action is subclass of User
    int UA_1, UA_2;
    User_action()
    {
        UA_1=5; UA_2 = 6;
    }

}
```

Seller_action is subclass of Seller

```
class Seller_action extends Seller{   //Seller action is subclass of Seller
    int SA_1, SA_2;
    Seller_action()
    {
        SA_1=7; SA_2 = 8;
    }
}
```

And then you create the following Objects(which inherit all the values from their parent):

```
User_action ua = new User_action();
Seller_action sa = new Seller_action();

ArrayList<Object>[][] table = new ArrayList[10][10];
table[0][0] = new ArrayList<Object>(); // add another ArrayList object to [0,0]
table[0][0].add(ua); // add object to that ArrayList
```

Comment: Many thanks...that really helped a lot...I have a rather silly question. Sorry, about that , So, in the following code: ArrayList<Object>[][] list1 = new ArrayList[2][2];           Where Object is written, I am not expected to mention the two different kinds of Objects???

Comment: Hi I changed the answer. I think an ArrayList of Object would be the best soluton. An object will have 2 properties, x and y co-ordinate. And your x  = ua.something and y = sa.something

Comment: No, actually I preferred the previous one ArrayList<Object>[][] list1 = new ArrayList[2][2]. I get this error when I do it:The expression of type ArrayList[][] needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<Process>[][]

Comment: How can I make this two dimensional List<Coordinates> myList = new ArrayList<Coordinates>(); And, then for every position store one object..??

Comment: I have edited my answer..please try. This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is have 2 super classes: 1 - Agent, 2 - Action. The each has 2 sub classes and the action has a User value. You can then create an array of Actions